# Is there any way to known which condition in re.fullmatch wasn't met?

Tags: python, match, python-re

I need to check if the string fulfil the conditions:

- at least 4 characters
- must consist of only letters
- at least 1 upper letter

I've got:

```
if not re.fullmatch(r'^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{4,}$', 'ab7c'):
   print('The string is wrong')
```

May I know which conditions were not met?
In my example, they are:

- must consist of only letters
- at least 1 upper letter

Comment: There's not, it's evaluated as a single expression. Also, you should remove the comma. If there are only letters, it will match strings of four or more characters. `{m,}` means `{m,∞}` ;)

Comment: Thank you for your noticing! I've just realised that my code accepts all special symbols and  A_bc or A,bc will pass the check. Is the next option correct?

Comment: if not re.fullmatch(r'^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(^(?:(?!,).)*?$).{4,}$', 'Abc_'):
       print('The string is wrong')

Comment: This will match your spec: `re.match(r'^(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Za-z]{4}$', string)` --- `^` and `$` match the start and the end of string (so you no longer need `fullmatch`) --- `(?=.*[A-Z])` is a lookbehind, it won't capture or consume anything, but no one will match if it doesn't, and it will match the first uppercase to appear from there onwards, --- and lastly `[A-Za-z]{4}` matches only a string with four letters.

Comment: @ Nuno André , I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just perform each assertion separately:

```py
def checkString(input):
    msg = ''
    if len(input) < 4:
        msg = '  -length must be 4 or more characters'
    if re.search(r'[^A-Za-z]', input):
        msg = msg + '\n  -input must consist of only letters'
    if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', input):
        msg = msg + '\n  -input must have at least one uppercase letter'

    if msg:
        print('The input fails validation:\n  ' + msg.strip())

checkString('ab7')
```

This prints:

```
The input fails validation:
  -length must be 4 or more characters
  -input must consist of only letters
  -input must have at least one uppercase letter
```

However, if the input be missing just one criterion, then we would get:

```
checkString('ABC3')

The input fails validation:
  -input must consist of only letters
```

Comment: Also, you can use string methods rather than regexes to make this (arguably) more readable: `input.isascii() and input.isalpha()` and `input.lower() != input` respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me, the first option is gorgeous!